# How do I request client geolocation in Vaadin 8 application?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

Tried embedding this JS code into the UI: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp but nothing happens.

Is there any way to achieve this in a Vaadin 8 app?

Answer (score 0):

There couple of approaches to do this in Vaadin 8. In both cases you need to create custom component with client side part. The component can be based on GWT or be JavaScript component. In case of GWT based component, you need to use native JavaScript blocks. There is good example of that here in this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/heruan/vaadin-geolocation/blob/master/geolocation-addon/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/geolocation/client/GeolocationConnector.java

The above implementation has been released as an [GeoLocation add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/geolocation-add-on) in Vaadin Directory. So you do not need to re-invent the wheel, if you do not want to.